# Put polyurethane on marble?

Tags: finishing, protection, marble

Is it ok to put polyurethane as a protective coating on a marble countertop?

I want to protect the marble from scratches and staining by foods and other kitchen hazards.

Comment: I have never used poly but have used sealers made for granite ,marble and concrete in the past that protected the surface and added a little shine.

Comment: Poly will scratch and flake off, looking worse than a few scratches in the stone. The marble is less likely to scratch as is why it is used as a cutting board surface. A sealer would be good to stop staining, however, bleach or a marble cleaner can be used to remove stains. Best to stay away from poly for this purpose.